# Computing the eigenvalues of $\mathbb{1}-I$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $A=\mathbb{1}-I \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$, the matrix having 0 in the diagonal and 1 everywhere else. To compute the eigenvalues I tried to compute the characteristic polynomial using recursion, but this turns out to be quite complicated, I think.

Is there some easier approach for finding the eigenvalues of such easy matrices? Maybe some guessing strategy?

And how, if we only have guessed some eigenvalues, do we know the (geometric) multiplicity of it?

Are there some easy tricks?

Comment: This is easy if you know all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\Bbb 1$.

Comment: I guess there I have somehow the same problem, however, there guessing is much easier. So $(1, \dotsc, 1)$ should be an eigenvector of $1$ with eigenvalue $n$. I am not sure whether there are others and not sure how to determine the multiplicity. 
Moreover, I am not sure how the eigenvalues of $1$ help me to get the ones of $I$ - this is due to the special form and not always the case for a sum of matrices, isn't it?

Comment: See 5xum's answer below for "how to deal with $I$".  Another way to think about it is to note that *every* vector is an eigenvector of $I$, so $\Bbb 1 - I$ will have the same eigenvectors as $\Bbb 1$.

Comment: As for how to deal with $\Bbb 1$... note that $\Bbb 1$ is a rank 1 matrix.  What can you say about a matrix whose rank is $1$?

Comment: I am trying to read through all the answers and comments. Thanks for it. So since $1$ has rank 1, it only has one non-zero eigenvalue and hence the one I mentioned above is the only one. Then, using the relation to get from $1$ to $1-I$, we can easily find that $n-1$ must be an eigenvalue to the eigenvector $(1, \dotsc, 1)$. From the 0 eigenvalue of $A$ we get to the eigenvalues $-1$ of multiplicity $n-1$. This is due to the fact 5xum mentioned, and not applicable for all sums of matrices?

Comment: That's about the sum of it.  The fact that 5xum mentions holds for any multiple of the identity too: for a matrix $A$ and constant $\mu$, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $x$, then $\lambda + \mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A + \mu I$ with the same eigenvector $x$.

Comment: But yes, the multiples of the identity matrix are special in this regard.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Is this also true the other way round and also with the same multiplicities? 
So $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $x$ iff $\lambda +  \mu$ is an eigevalue of $A + \mu I$ with eigenvector $x$, and in particular all eigenvalues have the same (geometric) multiplicity?

Comment: Yep. Note that since $\mu$ can be negative (or anything really), the forward statement implies its own converse.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. As I am no mathematician, I really appreciate your "easy-to-handle" answers and your patience. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the rank of the matrix $\mathbb{1}$ is $1$.  Therefore, it has one nonzero eigenvalue and $n-1$ zero eigenvalues.  The nonzero eigenvalue is $n$ corresponding to the vector of ones.  The remaining eigenvector corresponds to $e_1-e_i$ (for $i=2,\dots,n$).

Now, use @5xum 's answer to compute the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 5):

The main thing you need to use is:

> For any matrix $A$, $Ax = \lambda x$ is true if and only if $(A-I)x = (\lambda - 1)x$

Answer (score 3):

Let $z$ denote the vector consisting of only $1$s.  We can write $A$ as
$$
A = zz^T - I
$$
In particular, 
$$
Ax = zz^Tx - Ix = \langle z,x \rangle z - x 
$$

Now, consider two cases: first, suppose that $x=z$.  We then have
$$
Ax = Az = \langle z,z \rangle z - z = (\langle z,z \rangle  - 1)z
$$
Next, suppose $x$ is perpendicular to $z$.  We then have
$$
Ax = \langle z,x \rangle z - x = -x
$$
We may use this information to get a basis of eigenvectors, and deduce that the eigenvalues are $-1$ and $\|z^2\| - 1$.

Comment: This is the one and only elegant solution here. No explicit components and chosen coordinate frames, not even an explicit dimensionality, just the symmetry-preserving information about the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it "by hand" here :

You have that

$$(Ax)_i = \left( \sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)  - x_i$$

So if $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_x$, this imply that

$$\forall i \in [|1,n|], \left( \sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right) = (\lambda_x+1) x_i $$

- if $\lambda_x \neq -1$

$$\forall i \in [|1,n|], x_i = \frac{\left( \sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)}{\lambda_x+1}$$

This imply that

$x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = \cdots = x_n $

And $\lambda_x = n-1$

- if $\lambda_x = -1$, this imply that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n x_k = 0$$

So

$$x \in \{ (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{n-1} , - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_k ) \}$$

Or

$$x \in \text{Span} \left\{  e_1-e_n, e_2-e_n, \cdots, e_{n-1}-e_n \right\}$$